# mysql one where dependent to other

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make count of products which has been disabled and have options.
First I try to check in one table oc_product are product is disabled and then I want to check by this status (if disabled product) and product id check in another table are this product id have options.

I try like this, but thus only show result of status=0 products.

```
select COUNT(*) 
FROM oc_product 
WHERE status=0 
  AND product_id IN ( SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_option)
```

Comment: of course, because you added status = 0 right? what is your problem then?

Comment: hm, I need to count where product in oc_product is set to status=0, and then from that results to check how many products with status 0 in oc_product_option has rows.

Comment: And what is wrong with your current query?

Comment: This query gives to me products where status=0, but don't check how many rows have set option in oc_product_option

Answer (score 0):

If I unrestood your question, you want to join the tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oc_product ocp
INNER JOIN oc_product_option ocpo ON ocpo.product_id = ocp.id
WHERE ocp.status=0
```

so only those rows will returns where `product_id` in option table ( `ocpo.product_id = ocp.id`)

Comment: @Marty  i used your query and run in my database!it's working fine!i am getting the same response as you require.

Comment: @kiran gadhvi #1064 - you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mariadb server version for the right syntax to use near 'ocp INNER JOIN oc_product_option ocpo ON ocpo.product_id = ocp.id WHERE ocp.st' at line 1

Comment: which query are you running?i am talking about this query select COUNT(*) 
FROM oc_product 
WHERE status=0 
  AND product_id IN ( SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_option)

Comment: I talked about your. Yes my query is running, but this query show COUNT where status = 0, don't check in options table..

Comment: try this. SELECT COUNT(*) from oc_product as  ocp
INNER JOIN oc_product_option as ocpo ON ocpo.product_id = ocp.product_id
WHERE ocp.status=0

Comment: I forgot the `FROM`, try to add it. I've edited my post. Of course, also change the name of tables to real table names.

Comment: yes, i already knew it  that's why i modified the query! see my modified query above.

Comment: @lolka_bolka error caused because of ,you forgot to add from cluase in query!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a count of all the products with status 0, and also a count of all the products with a status of 0 which have options.

If so, LEFT OUTER JOIN products with options. Then you can count the DISTINCT product_id from the products table to get the count of product, and you can count the DISTINCT product_id from the product options table to get a count of the products with options. COUNT(column_name) doesn't count rows where the column_name value is NULL, hence won't count products where no matching options were found.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT oc_product.product_id) AS product_count,
        COUNT(DISTINCT oc_product_option.product_id) AS product_with_options_count
FROM oc_product 
LEFT OUTER JOIN oc_product_option
ON oc_product.product_id = oc_product_option.product_id
WHERE oc_product.status = 0
```